# How do I add a reference to a Shared Code project (.shproj) from another project

Tags: c#, .net, vb.net, visual-studio

When I created a new universal app project in Visual Studio it created a shared project that let me share code between the Windows Phone 8.1 and Windows 8.1 projects that were created.

Now I have other projects that I would also like to use that shared code.  However, I do not see a way to add select that project in the "Add Reference..." window.

If I try to copy the reference from one of the existing projects I get the error:

> Catastrophic failure (Exception from HRESULT: 0x8000FFFF
>   (E_UNEXPECTED))

when I click 'Paste Reference'. How do I reference the shared project from other projects?

Answer (score 40, accepted):

Adding the reference will require editing the project files where you want to add it.  If it helps, you can peek at the project file where it is already referenced to see a working example.

Near the bottom of the project file (ex, a .csproj) there is likely already an `<Import>` element such as

```xml
<Project ...>
  [...]
  <Import Project="$(MSBuildToolsPath)\Microsoft.CSharp.targets" />
</Project>
```

You add the Shared project by adding another element like that for the Shared project. For example:

```xml
<Project ...>
  [...]
  <Import Project="..\Shared\Shared.projitems" Label="Shared" />
  <Import Project="$(MSBuildToolsPath)\Microsoft.CSharp.targets" />
</Project>
```

It is important for the Label attribute to be set to "Shared."  If you set it to something else it will not be recognized as a Shared project by Visual Studio and will not appear under References. Project should be set to the path to the appropriate ".projitems" file.

Comment: It would be nice to see here, how to add a reference to a dll as well.

Comment: I wish that in visual studio 2017, you didn't have to hack the .csproj file

Comment: @Omzig does [@theguy's answer for VS2017](https://stackoverflow.com/a/46131355/1072626) not work?  I can't test it.

Comment: Correct Vossad01, the "Shared Projects" tab is missing. Unless you have to do something dumb and enable it.

Comment: Apparently my problem with shared projects has something to do with the Unit Tests that I am running. https://developercommunity.visualstudio.com/content/problem/184544/shared-projects-missing.html

Comment: I had the issue in VS 15.6.6 at a webapi2 project. So it's not limited to unit testing.

Comment: @JPHellemons I like your suggestion the best. That way I can navigate to the shared project on my dev machine, add it as an existing reference and let Visual Studio handle how it puts that into the solution file. Then go to whatever project I want to use the shared project from and an a reference to the imported shared project.

Answer (score 11):

Visual Studio 2017:

Right-click the References or Dependencies item in the Solution Explorer and choose "Add Reference..."

[image: Dependencies or References context menu]

The Reference Manager will open. Click "Shared Project" on the left side of the Reference Manager

[image]

Then select your project and click OK.

Comment: This *should* theoretically work for VS2015 as well (the same tabs are all present). However I ran into the problem where the shared project was not listed for some reason.

Comment: @MageXy are you sure these are visual studio 2017 screenshots? my VS2017 doesn't have "Shared Projects" /grr

Comment: I do not see "Shared Projects" in the Reference Manager in VS2017

Comment: I am using VS 2017 and do have the Shared Projects on the left side of the Reference Manager. However, I cannot find a way to add the Shared Project. I clicked on the Browse... button, then tried added the .sln file, that failed. Then I tried adding the .shproj file, that failed.

Comment: Check your version of VS 2017.  There was a bug fix in 15.9 that will show the Shared Projects selection

Answer (score 4):

In **TargetProject.csproj** file add that string:

```
<Import Project="..\YourSharedProject\YourSharedProject.projitems" Label="Shared" Condition="Exists('..\YourSharedProject\YourSharedProject.projitems')" />
```

Comment: This worked for me.  VS2019 - If I added an "existing" project to the solution, only then would it allow me to add a "shared" project reference to the target.  This is through the GUI.  If I just added a line like the one above directly to the target csproj, it worked, too.

Answer (score 0):

Check your version of Visual Studio.  in VS2017 there was a bug fix for version 15.9 which will show the Shared Project selector.  Click Tools -> Update to get the lastest version of VS

Answer (score -3):

Check out the [Shared Project Reference Manager](https://visualstudiogallery.msdn.microsoft.com/315c13a7-2787-4f57-bdf7-adae6ed54450) extension.